# simple raster format to use in Web applications?

Tags: raster, javascript, geojson, esri-grid-format

I'm building a Web application in which users create and edit very coarse raster data. They're assigning values to cells in a georeferenced grid. Right now I'm storing the values in a multidimensional JavaScript array; for example:

```
[
  ['yes', 'no', 'maybe'],
  ['no', 'no', 'yes']
]
```

and I'm storing latitudes and longitudes for the bounding box, along with the number of rows and columns, as separate values on the overall object.

That works, but I'm just curious to know if there are any standard GIS data formats amenable to JavaScript I can use. In effect, my question is: shapefile is to GeoJSON as [Esri grid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esri_grid) is to *what*?